# Inception v3 Graph Definition File Download

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to follow the transfer learning examples [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) and [2](https://www.kernix.com/blog/image-classification-with-a-pre-trained-deep-neural-network_p11), both use a pretrained Inception v3 model. Both refer to a graph definition file, `classify_image_graph_def.pb`.

Where can I download the original Inception v3 `.pb` file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seems you should follow the instructions from here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

to get sustainable results - the script employed within the lab loads the pre-trained Inception v3 model, removes the old top layer, and trains a new one on the images you've applied.

There is more recent version of Inception-v3 model available:
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

[From the official Github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception)

```
curl -O http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-v3-2016-03-01.tar.gz
```